# How do I hide my firebase API key in my firebase project?

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using javascript. I need to hide my api key.
i have been researching for hours but I cant find a fix.

Comment: You don't need to hide your api key. You can read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public